# Either or Condition in Postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I select the rows that have either X or Y in column C but not both in Postgres? Basically there should be no duplicate values in Column B.

Data :

```
     A      |      B      |     C      |
----------------------------------------
     1      |    John     |     X      |
----------------------------------------
     2      |    John     |     Y      |
----------------------------------------
     3      |    Sam      |     X      |
----------------------------------------
     4      |    May      |     Y      |
```

Result:

```
     A      |      B      |     C      |
----------------------------------------
     1      |    John     |     X      |
----------------------------------------
     3      |    Sam      |     X      |
----------------------------------------
     4      |    May      |     Y      |
```

Comment: You need to have a rule: For John, why did you select C=X over C=Y? Is it because the A= 1 is smaller than 2? is this the rule (return each unique Bs only where A is the smallest)? or is there a different rule, like X is smaller than Y?

Comment: Or it doesn't matter which row is returned as long as column B is unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DISTINCT ON clause:

```
select distinct on (b)
a, b, c
from data
order by b, a
```

In that case you will get the first row within every unique B value.

You can also use WINDOW FUNCTIONS  or GROUP BY clause if filtering with special conditions is required.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can count occurencies of 'X' and 'Y' for the every name (this is what x_or_y does) and then just pick those with count = 1

```
with x_or_y as (
select a, b, c, 
       count(case when upper(c) in ('X', 'Y') then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by b order by a) xy_cnt
  from test_t
 )
 
select a, b, c
  from x_or_y
 where xy_cnt = 1;
```

[enter link description here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/0)